# Wordpress is changing "-" into "—"

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm trying to write guitar tabs in WordPress, but I'm having a problem.

I input a line of a tab like so (I've tried the visual editor, text editor, and Elementor):

`|----------------------------------------------3----|`

But the browser renders it as

`|——————————————-3—-|`

I think it's converting "-" to "—".

I've tried using a monospace font which fixes it, but it messes up my spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your theme's `functions.php`or add it as a new snippet using `Code Snippets` plugin

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wptexturize' );
```

Comment: Yep. This is it!